# Drag Segue To Self in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to drag a segue from my viewcontroller, to itself. So I can push "infinite" instances of that particular view controller.

I know how to do this in code (I.e instansiate the view controller programmatically). However, I want to use segues as far as possible.

I've found a few "hacks" for making segue to self in storyboard, but I don't like hacks, so my question is;

Is there a clean way to make a segue back to self in the Storyboard? I dont want to drag it from a button or such, I just want a generic segue that i can use with:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: At the moment I am using a segue from tableviewcell to self instead. That is perhaps the cleanest way. But I got kind of shocked when I realised there was no way to make a clean segue back to oneself.

For example, if I want to fire this particular segue depending on other conditions, I will have to "hijack" the segue from a tableviewcell. It feels just ugly. But perhaps I do not need to worry about that.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. I get what you are doing with the segue by trying to get it to trigger itself, but why do you want to do that? Edit your question to describe your app function

Comment: Just drag the segue arrow back to itself in the storyboard ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in the storyboard itself. Drag a Storyboard Reference from the Object Library, and then control drag from your view controller to the storyboard reference to create a segue, and select the type of transition. Then with the storyboard reference selected, make sure it's attributes in the inspector are set to the same storyboard file, and the same view controller referenced by it's storyboard ID.

Answer (score -1):

You can drag the segue from the trigger to the same view controller. You'll need to drag it to the the yellow box in the top left, on top of the view controller in Xcode 6.

If you try to drag it onto the VC itself Xcode will think that you're trying to add a layout constraint.

Comment: There is no trigger, I want a generic segue. Xcode6 still not able to make one with the VC itself as a source.

Comment: You should be able to drag it from a view on your VC. Your top level view will do.

Answer (score -1):

You can embed your TableViewController in a Navigation Controller and segue to the Navigation controller.

Comment: Right. Did you try to embed your Controller View into a Container view twice inside 2 other ControllerViews and segue between those two?