# Collection View pushing segue onto itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I want to implemented a photo album like iOS app using collection view. The data hierarchy is multi-level data, where albums may exist within albums. The user can created unlimited level of albums. I have successfully created the first level with a collection view controller and link to a page view controller to create the detail level(if the cell is a photo instead of album). My problem is how to implement the multi-level album functionality. It is just a repetition of the first level view controller (all the functionality is exactly the same) with different data source. On the storyboard, I have tried to drag a segue from the view controller to push onto itself but Xcode does not allow. Do I have to duplicate the view controller, one for each level, but I don't know how many levels there are? Also, I am using navigation controller, I want each level to be added to the navigation stack as they are been opened. Please help.

Comment: I answered one like this where the collection view was a UITableView.  Its very possible (and simple) to do what you're aiming for if you forego the painted segue in IB.  See this answer... identical advice except think collection view rather than table view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115637/drill-down-hierarchical-data-with-uitableview/15116543#15116543

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I am looking for. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "clean way" of dragging a segue to self.

But there's hacky ways, ofc! I.e. create a button / barbuttonitem which you hide, and drag the segue from there. :-)

See this question (asked by me a while back):

[Drag Segue To Self in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937496/drag-segue-to-self-in-storyboard)

Comment: I tried but still cannot drag the segue to self in the storyboard. Anyway, I have tried danh's solution and it works for me. Thanks for helping.